# Python: Create a log file every day in schedule module -> simple question

Tags: python, loops, logging, scheduler, schedule

I run a python program everyday via `schedule` module and I also want to create a log file on daily basis.

The code is like:

```
import time
import datetime
import schedule
import logging

def run_bot():
    print('start to work!')
    logging.basicConfig(filename='log/{}.log'.format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d")))
    logging.warning('{} # Logging starts # '.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%x %X")))       


schedule.every().day.at("11:59").do(run_bot)
 

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The code above works at the beginning and it creates a log file.

However, it will not create log file every day. All logs will be written into one log file created in day one.

If I want to create a new log file everyday, then I need to manually run the program everyday.

Is there anyway a new log file is created automatically without interrupting the program.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler)

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't stop running, so it keeps using the same log file. Consider using a [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) instead, that should open a new log file. The log file name won't be exactly the way you want it, though it will have the time in the name.